# Set Cookies not setting up in the browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, aws-lambda, setcookie

I'm using AWS Lambda function setup with the API Gateway. I have been trying to set-cookies to the application but even though it shows in the console headers, it is not setting up in the browser.

```
  callback(null, {
        statusCode: 302,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
            'Location': "https://example.com",
            'Set-Cookie': cookieString,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'


        },
        body: null
    } );
```

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simply-serverless-using-aws-lambda-to-expose-custom-cookies-with-api-gateway/
Tried implementing this but in the browser cookies were not set.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you calling this using Ajax or http get request while loading a page?

Comment: I'm calling an http get request from a simple static form, even though the page redirects, cookie is not setting in the browser

Comment: Change the content type Content-Type: text/htm

Comment: Changed the content type, still the same though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the s3 bucket hosted static website to an API gateway, cookies passed

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Cookies.html

Comment: What exactly did you have to do? I read the link, but it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the **Path** of your cookie:

```
Set-Cookie:myCookie=foo; Path=/; HttpOnly
```